# Invoke-Command doesn't launch the executable on a remote workstation

Tags: powershell, active-directory, executable, uac, invoke-command

I'm trying to uninstall MS Office 2007 on all workstations in my Active Directory. For this, I have to launch `C:\Transfer2007\setup.exe` which is configured by the `UninstallConfig.xml` file for a silent uninstallation (located in the same directory). PowerShell's `Invoke-Command` doesn't return any errors and it seems as everything is fine, but the `setup.exe` never launches on the target workstation.

When I launch the setup.exe manually, I get the 'Open File - Security Warning' where I have to press 'Launch'. In the next step, I get asked for administrator access (UAC). I think these popups are the problem as to why the .exe never launches when trying to run it remotely through PowerShell.

I already tried to include the following in the code:

- `–ExecutionPolicy Bypass`
- `-Credential` parameter with admin rights

`UninstallationConfig.xml` file:

```xml
<Configuration Product="ProPlus">
  <Display Level="none" CompletionNotice="no" />
  <SettingId="SETUP_REBOOT" Value="AutoAlways" /> 
</Configuration>
```

PowerShell code:

```cs
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
    Set-Location "C:\Transfer2007\";
    .\SETUP.exe /uninstall ProPlus /config \UninstallConfig.xml
} -Credential mmb -ComputerName $Computer -AsJob
```

Answer (score 0):

Try execute this ScriptBlock

```
$app = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product |
Where-Object {$_.Name -match "Office"}
$app.Uninstall()
```

OR

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server01 -ScriptBlock { 
Start-Process 'C:\Transfer2007\SETUP.exe' -ArgumentList '/uninstall ProPlus /config \UninstallConfig.xml' -Wait 
} -Credential (Get-Credential 'localhost\Administrator') -ComputerName $Computer -AsJob
```

Comment: This seems to work only partially. When the script is executed, I can see the MS Office still installed in the Control Panel. However I am not able to run it. Restarting doesn't help. So it's probably not a clean way of uninstalling

Comment: Ok. Try This.
---
`Invoke-Command -ComputerName server01 -ScriptBlock { 
    Start-Process 'C:\Transfer2007\SETUP.exe' -ArgumentList '/uninstall ProPlus /config \UninstallConfig.xml' -Wait
} -Credential mmb -ComputerName $Computer -AsJob`